# append lines after another files line by line

Tags: shell, awk

Append one file,

```
011C0201.WAV
011C0202.WAV
011C0203.WAV
011C0204.WAV
011C0205.WAV
```

After another file,

```
52 601
39 608
56 1016
39 416
65 335
```

result is the following, also divide by tab

```
011C0201.WAV    52_601_011C0201
011C0202.WAV    39_608_011C0202
011C0203.WAV    56_1016_011C0203
011C0204.WAV    39_416_011C0204
011C0205.WAV    65_335_011C0205
```

Here is what I do

```
awk '
NR==FNR { start=$1; end=$2; next}
{ print $0 start end }
' WSJ_310P_PC_16k.epd WSJ_310P_PC_16k.spt > tmp
```

But it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `paste` + `awk`?

```
$ paste one another | 
    awk '{print $1, $2 "_" $3 "_" substr($1,1,length($1)-4)}' OFS='\t'
011C0201.WAV    52_601_011C0201
011C0202.WAV    39_608_011C0202
011C0203.WAV    56_1016_011C0203
011C0204.WAV    39_416_011C0204
011C0205.WAV    65_335_011C0205
```

If you prefer to do it entirely in `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[FNR]=$0; next} {print a[FNR], $1 "_" $2 "_" substr(a[FNR],1,length(a[FNR])-4)}' OFS='\t' one another
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one using pure `awk`

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next}
    {
        split(a[FNR],b,".");
        printf "%s\t%s_%s_%s\n", a[FNR], $1, $2, b[1]
    }
' file1 file2
```